# How to access methods inside of data table

Tags: c#, asp.net

Before i had a similar question but i did not get answer:

[How to get column values from a data set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40789965/how-to-get-column-values-from-a-data-set)

I have made a data set and inside of this data set there is one data table with 2 methods first method is (Get all product) and second is a parameter query (Get product by code) , i like to know how can access to second method of data table (parameter query) by code.

Actually i am working with grid view and detail view , first methods fills grid view and second method fills detail view after selecting a row in grid view. Now i want to get value of (Id) from grid view after selecting row in grid view and put in second method of data table for getting other values and save in variable.

this is previouse code:

I also added another query to data set, it's name is Get Data By Code(@code), it works with select method of detail view.

```
     SELECT  Code, Products.Name, Dsc, Price, CategoryID,  ImagePath,    ThumbnailPath
     FROM            Products where Code=@Code
```

Now when I use DetailsView1_ItemUpdating of detail view I would like to get old (ImagePath) and old (ThumbnailPath) and save in string variable.

```
    protected void DetailsView1_ItemUpdating(object sender,       DetailsViewUpdateEventArgs e)
  {
  FileUpload fu = (FileUpload)DetailsView1.FindControl("FileUpload1");
  if (fu != null && fu.HasFile)
  {
    string ImageName = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd_hhmmss") + fu.FileName.Substring(fu.FileName.LastIndexOf("\\") + 1);
    fu.SaveAs(Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + @"Images\Products\" + ImageName);

    System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + @"Images\Products\" + ImageName);
    img.GetThumbnailImage(100, 100, null, IntPtr.Zero).Save(Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + @"Images\Products\tmb_" + ImageName);
    img.Dispose();

    e.NewValues["ImagePath"] = ImageName;
    e.NewValues["ThumbnailPath"] = "tmb_" + ImageName;
}
```

}

I like getting old ImagePath and old ThumbnailPath (before update) with using methods in data set or by select query.

Comment: Please take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please provide your code was you already tried to get a better idea what you are asking for and get better help.